# Screen Glitch (half of screen goes black and all objects are gone)

Tags: technical-issues, clash-of-clans, android

[image: Every thing disappears its very annoying]Anyone knows how to fix this stupid bug it happens at random I lose in war because of this.

Phone:

Samsung Galaxy Note 2

Android 4.4 (Kitkat)

No root/ No custom rom

side Note-

1. You see it fixes after you restart your app but what is the point I ll lose in war
2. fix should be permanent or at least any thing that does not require restart

Comment: Can you give more details, like the type of phone you are using, and what happens before this happens? We need details to help.

Comment: It happens at random I don't know the cause

Comment: Is the bug _just_ half the screen turning black? Is there sound? Any other details you can give about it?

Comment: sound is there but all objects are gone as it is shown in image and apparently this is the only bug

Comment: I recommend using a more descriptive question title.

Comment: Does closing the app and reopening it fix the issue? Or does it persist? Does it only happen during wars or have you seen it happen during normal attacks or to your own base?

Comment: I think the new edited description is more than enough

Comment: And It happens at random even while visiting other bases. It is not limited to war but it also happens during raid etc do you get what I mean

Comment: The app is updated to latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem:-

For those people who have the same problem, here is a temporary fix:

I guess supercell would fix this bug later

I have found out that this bug happens in some of the **samsung** devices:

Fixes

1. If you are having black screen while you have visited other's base or your own base (just keeping on tapping left side where screen is black) and eventually you'll tap the boat and the screen would be fixed.
2. IF you are in war and have not attacked yet then just press the back button of the phone and the screen is fixed.

I hope this helps.